# An Error Was Encountered Non-existent class: Facebook using codeigniter 3

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter-3

Hi I have this `'facebook-php-sdk-v4-5.0.0'` downloaded file from facebook developers site. I already created a app in developers.facebook.com and have already a API and Secret key.

I already extracted the `'facebook-php-sdk-v4-5.0.0'` to the application/libraries folders and and inside the folder `facebook-php-sdk-v4-5.0.0/src/Facebook` I moved the Facebook folder into `application/libraries/Facebook`.

Now in my login controller I loaded the facebook library into this one

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Login extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library('facebook');
        $this->fb = $this->facebook;
    }
}
```

This is what I get and error:

```
An Error Was Encountered

Non-existent class: Facebook
```

Can someone help me figured this thing out?

Any help is much appreciated. TIA